# Qt5.2 QNetwork, how many bytes are writed?

Tags: c++, qt, networking

I am working in a networking software using Qt5.2, so:

```
QTcpSocket m_socket;    
m_socket.connectToHost(m_host, m_port);
if (qint64 ret = m_socket.write(data, static_cast<qint64>(*n_bytes)) != -1)
{
    m_socket.waitForBytesWritten(timeout);
}
```

If some bytes are writed (not equal to `*n_bytes`), `m_socket.waitForBytesWritten(timeout)` return false?
I need determine the number of bytes written, for my algoritm,
"retry the write operation using the number of bytes written as offset for the start (data + offset)."

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qiodevice.html#write

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: The number of bytes returned by `QIODevice::write()` is the number of bytes written. Use that.

Any bytes it says are written, you don't need to write them again. They are buffered and will be delivered as soon as possible, and there's no way to take them back.

Only possibility of partial write is, if connection breaks before everything is transmitted. In that case you have no *direct* way to find out how many bytes were actually received by the other side. You *could* have a protocol, which reconnects in case of unexpected disconnect, and asks how many bytes the other side receives, but that is higher level logic and Qt will not help you with that.

If `QIODevice::waitForBytesWritten()` returns false, it means everything was not sent (to the OS or whatever) within the timeout, or there was a disconnect. In that case your options are:

- Wait longer, in case sending data is slow for some reason
- Disconnect (and possibly reconnect)

---

Note: using `QIODevice::waitForBytesWritten()` can cause GUI to hang until it returns, or as the docs put it:

> Warning: Calling this function from the main (GUI) thread might cause your user interface to freeze.

You should use `QIODevice::bytesWritten()` signal for tracking how much is being sent. Note that even if it gives you less bytes than you wrote, it just means you should be getting that signal again soon, reporting that more bytes were written (or you might get disconnect signal telling that nothing more will be written). So you still mustn't write any bytes again.

Overall, you should avoid using any `waitForXxxx()` methods of Qt together with an event loop (unless it is a quick hack or a throw-away project or something like that). They can be convenient, but in the end they can cause unexpected problems in event-based program flow. Just write the slots and connect signals, it's not many minutes of extra work.